# Drag scrolls UITableView itself instead of its contents

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, scroll

I have several table UIs in an iPad app, each with a UITableView embedded in a larger, grey-background UIView, which in turn is embedded in a full-screen, clear-color UIView (to detect taps outside the grey UI as a signal to dismiss it).

The view controller owns the top UIView and sets itself as the delegate for the embedded table's dataSource and delegate protocols.

All but the latest UI work as expected: when I drag up and down on the table, the contents scroll up and down, exposing blank white space when scrolled beyond the top/bottom of the contents. When I release the drag while scrolled beyond the top/bottom of the table, the contents bounce back to the full height of the table.

But in this latest UI, when I drag up and down, the entire table view scrolls rather than its content, exposing grey background beyond the top/bottom of the table view.

This causes two problems: I can't reach any of the table cells outside those initially visible, and when dragged past the bottom, the table doesn't bounce back to its full height. The former obviously is worse than the latter, but both are bad.

As far as I can tell, the .xib files and code that manages these UIs are the same for all. (Which was my intent when I created them.) I can't find any difference, certainly no difference that would explain this behavior.

Can any one offer suggestions where I should look to find what's making the table view itself scroll, rather than its contents?

I can post code snippets and screen captures of the .xib's in Xcode 4, but as I said, they all appear to be identical in these UIs.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I was making a call on the UITableView to draw round corners on the right side while leaving the left side corners square (so the icon in each table cell's imageView wouldn't have its corners chopped off).

The code came from a blog post on InfinixSoft's web site: http://infinixsoft.com/2012/09/rounding-up-the-corners-of-a-uiview

It was this call that caused the entire table view to scroll instead of just its contents. Removing this call fixed the problem.

I hope this answer helps other developers.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.